# jquery minDate not working for date validation

Tags: jquery

I have to input boxes where each receive dates from jquery datepicker. Now am trying to validate the calendar from the first input to not allow previous dates from past days that no longer exist.

With reference to this question, I added the following code under the "numberOfMonts" and it happens the following:

```
minDate: 0,
```

I select the "from" date as I want, but when click on the "to" date I can still select dates before the current chosen date on the "from field".

Hope you can understand from my [snippet here](http://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/MmWdGv)

Here is the code I have working without validation.
How can I validate the calendar correctly to not select old dates?

Here my full JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    $("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
      $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
  });
  var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
  $("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
    console.log($('.selected .value').text());
  });
    var txtFromDate, txtToDate;
  $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "d/M/yy",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtFromDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
      $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
  });
  $("#txtTo").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtToDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
      $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
  });

  $('a#atributo').click(function() {
     var monthNames = [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
        "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
        "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
        "Nov", "Dec"
      ];

    var date1 = $("#txtFrom").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_1  = date1.getDate(),  
        month_1 = date1.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_1 =  date1.getFullYear();

    var date2 = $("#txtTo").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_2  = date2.getDate(),  
        month_2 = date2.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_2 =  date2.getFullYear(); 


    var people = $('#search-pax :selected').val();

    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/"+where+"?q="+where+"&start="+day_1+"+"+monthNames[month_1]+"+"+year_1+'&end='+day_2+'+'+monthNames[month_2]+'+'+year_2+'&pax='+people);
  });
});
```

How can I validate the calendar properly

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#dt1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (date) {
      var dt2 = $('#dt2');
      var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      dt2.datepicker('setDate', minDate);
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30);
      //sets dt2 maxDate to the last day of 30 days window
      dt2.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
      dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
      $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
    }
  });
  $('#dt2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
  });
});
```

Example html may look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> <label for="to">to</label> <input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>
```

Comment: Nothing more perfect that. Voted

Answer (score 0):

```
// Change inside onSelect as follow :
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "d/M/yy",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $('#txtTo').datepicker('option', {
            minDate: $(this).datepicker('getDate')
        });
    }
});
```